# Why is vm host only and NAT networking not working?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines

I've got a VMbox ruining Ubuntu set up to use host only and NAT networking.

The issue is that the `nat network` can not connect [NAT networking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUCjF.png) 
I've set the interfaces as shown below:

```
GNU nano 2.8.6                   File: /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5). 

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Host-only interface
auto enp0s3
iface  enp0s3 inet dhcp

#Nat
auto enp0s8
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

Is there any issue with the above file?

Comment: You'll need to post the output of `ip addr`, just the `/etc/network/interfaces` output isn't really enough to help here. What's the actual issue? Is the guest getting an IP? Are you not able to load web-pages? What about DNS, does it resolve google.com to an IP? Can you ping things like 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Why do you say `eth2`? That doesn't seem to be the name of the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We really would need to see the output of of `ip addr` to know more, but as pointed out by @Michael Hampton in the comments, your configuration doesn't line up with the way the system is configured.

This block *could* indicate that you have a second interface being detected by the system with the name of `enp0s8` (without `ip addr` we can't confirm).

```
#Nat
auto enp0s8
```

But, you've setup `eth2` to be DHCP instead

```
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

This isn't going to work if the interface isn't known as `eth2`.

Instead, try this:

```
#Nat
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```